# Missing argument for parameter #2 in call

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I really can't see why this error appears.

Missing argument for parameter #2 in call

```
if hero.position.y * scale != CGPointMake(body.size.height + kADGroundHeight+4) * scale {
    removeAllActions()
}
```

Comment: Well, `CGPointMake` takes 2 arguments, and you've given it 1 ...

Comment: option-click on `CGPointMake` to see its declaration.

Comment: Why are you using `CGPointMake`? You just need a value, not a point.